# Understanding the position operator in Reed and Simon Mathematical physics vol 1.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am studying the subject of unbounded operators and I cannot understand some statements that appear in the book by Reed, Simon

[image]

Question 1. The statement "support near plus or minus infinity" means that $\text{supp}(\varphi)=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\varphi(x)\neq 0\text{ and } x\geq R \text{ some } R>0 \text{ sufficiently large } \right\}$?

Question 2. Why we can make $\left\|T\varphi\right\|$ as large as we like while keeping $\left\|\varphi\right\|=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "support near $\pm \infty$" is a poor choice is words. I would instead just take $\phi$ to be the characteristic function of the interval $[n,n+1]$ for $n$ large enough, and a simple computation would give $\|T\phi\|>n$, hence pretty large.